# Keeping data when Android does an onExit()

Tags: android, arrays, listview, onresume

I have a String array that I want to keep to display in a ListView, but every time I exit the activity, the global String array is deleted and the ListView doesn't display.  Is there anyway that I can keep a String array in the application's storage for the next use?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty easy for just a string. You can store it in shared preferences. See this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref